# Python-Selenium: Title is returning empty on website when using Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python, firefoxdriver

I am having this weird issue where when I use:

```
title = driver.title
print('Title is: ' + title)
```

the title returns blank or empty, it returns blank only on Firefox and with our internal website. When I use Chrome on our website it returns the actual title or if I use FF on different websites they all return the title too.

This test was running fine until a few weeks ago, Our Developers can't figure out what change might be causing this issue, Of course, I can use Wait but our concern is what else might have broken.

Comment: It might be a compatibility issue, check your browser versions against selenium version.

Comment: Doesn't look like its a version issue, checked it with versions which were working before.

Comment: Adding to the version suggestion... If you are using a Firefox version greater than 47 you need to switch to the Marionette driver.

Comment: I guess it's now called Gecko driver. I am using it presently

Comment: Can you please list Firefox, Selenium and Python versions ?

Comment: upvoting just because of the informative titile

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think of the compatibility issue between Selenium and Firefox, please check that first.

Or, it might very well be a *timing issue* - you are getting the page title at the time it is not set, though I have not experienced similar timing issues with page titles before.

If this is the case, you may apply [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) with `title_is` or `title_contains` Expected Condition function:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.title_contains("desired substring"))

title = driver.title
print('Title is: ' + title)
```